# Error - The name 'GetSuppliers' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have a web forms application running vs2013. I am building the application using the code first model.

I have a datacontext class and an initialiser class to seed some initial data. Everything was working fine until I decided to change the model and make some changes to the relationships between my classes and add 4 more. Now I get  4 errors in the initialiser class saying that "The name 'xxxxx' does not exist in the current context" which is weird since there 6 other similar statements working fine.

I have cleaned, rebuilt the Solution. Restarted my computer. I don't know what else to try. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

myDataContext:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YPGOOS.Models
{
    public class myDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public myDataContext() : base("YPGOOS") { }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Style> Styles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QuantityBreak> QuantityBreaks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Finish> Finishes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FinishConstraint> FinishConstraints { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FinishAttribute> FinishAttributes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then myDatabaseInitialiser class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace YPGOOS.Models
{
    //public class myDatabaseInitialiser : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<myDataContext>
    public class myDatabaseInitialiser : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<myDataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(myDataContext context)
        {
            GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
            GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
            GetSizes().ForEach(s => context.Sizes.Add(s));
            GetQuantityBreaks().ForEach(q => context.QuantityBreaks.Add(q));
            GetStyles().ForEach(st => context.Styles.Add(st));
            GetStocks().ForEach(x => context.Stocks.Add(x));
            GetSuppliers().ForEach(su => context.Suppliers.Add(su));
            GetFinishes().ForEach(f => context.Finishes.Add(f));
            GetFinishConstraints().ForEach(fc => context.FinishConstraints.Add(fc));
            GetFinishAttributes().ForEach(fa => context.FinishAttributes.Add(fa));
        }

        private static List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            var categories = new List<Category> {
                new Category
                {
                    CategoryID = 1,  etc
```

I added the last 4 recently; GetSuppliers, GetFinishes, GetFinishConstraints, GetFinishAttributes and it's on these 4 I'm getting the error.

Here's the Supplier class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YPGOOS.Models
{
    public class Supplier
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int SupplierID { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Supplier Name")]
        public string SupplierName { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(4), Display(Name = "Supplier Code")]
        public string SupplierCode { get; set; }

        //Navigation Properties
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public DbSet<Size> Suppliers { get; set; }
```

Why is Suppliers a Generic of Size? You have a Supplier class. Is it just a typo? Did intellisense start acting like autocorrect?

Comment: Thanks for that Chad, it was just a typo :-) No intellisense seems to be acting normally just can't get rid of those red squiggly lines that I don't think should be there!

Answer (score 0):

Embarrassed to give the answer on this one, real newbie issue. I simply didn't have a method called GetSuppliers() in the DatabaseInitialiser class - as soon as I put that in the error disappeared.